# Requests to subdomain should point to subdirectory

Tags: subdomain, iis-7

Is there a way to have requests to subdomains have files served from subdirectories?
The sites should regard their folders as root.

example:
A request to blog.mydomain.com should serve the page ./blog/default.aspx which has an img tag like

```
<img alt="logo" src="/content/pics/logo.png" />
```

which should serve the ./blog/content/pics/logo.png file.
When I run the same site on my localhost the site will not be in a subdir /blog and the same page should still serve the correct image.

My site is hosted on an IIS7 shared hosting site (discountasp.net) and preferably deployed with the webdeployer. I have IIS manager to my disposal.
Any help?

**UPDATE**

1. The IIS manager connection to the discountasp account doesn't contain the "Sites" node as illustrated in the image below
2. DiscountAsp support is swift :)
   They suggested I would have a redirect script in my main that would take the job of redirecting any request to the correct subpath. This is not really an option as this requires me to merge all my applications into one big one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making a seperate site in IIS, using the subdomain address, but just pointing to the subdirectory as the root directory?

Comment: I would if I could. The "Sites" node is invisible in my IIS manager so I'm assuming I don't have the rights to create multiple sites on my shared hosting account. I'm going to mail them about this after work.

Comment: Updated original post with the conversation going on between aspdiscount support ppl an me

Answer (score 0):

Try in IIS:

- Right click site
- Add Virtual Directory

Comment: See OP on why this is impossible